# C++: Is it possible to detach the char* pointer from an std::string object?

Tags: c++, string, stdstring

I am using the std::string type for my string manipulations.

However, sometimes I need to keep the raw char* pointer, even after the original std::string object is destroyed (yes, I know the char* pointer references the HEAP and must eventually be disposed of).

However, looks like there is no way to detach the raw pointer from the string or is it?

Maybe I should use another string implementation?

Thanks.

**EDIT**

Folks, please do not confuse detaching with copying. The essence of detaching is for the string object to relinquish its ownership on the underlying buffer. So, had the string had the `detach` method, its semantics would be something like this:

```
char *ptr = NULL;
{
  std::string s = "Hello world!";
  ptr = s.detach(); // May actually allocate memory, if the string is small enough to have been held inside the static buffer found in std::string.
  assert(s == NULL);
}
// at this point s is destroyed
// ptr continues to point to a valid HEAP memory with the "Hello world!" string in it.
...
delete ptr; // need to cleanup
```

Comment: Probable duplicate: [How can I take ownership of a C++ std::string char data without copying and keeping std::string object?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/11301446)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

No, it is not possible to detach the pointer returned by `std::string::c_str()`.

Solution: Make a read-only copy of the string, and ensure that that copy lives at least as long as you need the char* pointer. Then use `c_str()` on that copy, and it will be valid as long as you want.

If that is not possible, then you won't be able to release the `char*` either. And any attempt to wrap that pointer in a RAII construction, will only re-invent parts of std::string.

Answer (score 4):

`std::string` allocates through `std:allocator` (or a template parameter). Even if you could detach the raw storage, you'd have to free it through `std::allocator` too. And you would of course want a RAII class to do that correctly.

Fortunately, there already is just such a RAII class in the standard libraries. It's called `std::string`.

The closest thing to a "detach" function, therefore, is `swap`. It detaches the resources from a string, and stores them in a form from which they can be correctly freed later (i.e., another string). In C++11, move assignment does that too.

```
std::string raii_for_ptr;
const char *ptr = NULL;
{
     std::string s = "Hello world!";
     raii_for_ptr.swap(s); // or raii_for_ptr = std::move(s)
     ptr = raii_for_ptr.c_str();
     assert(s == "");
}

// no need to cleanup
```

If your objective is to create for yourself the need to call `delete` on something, then (a) that's absurd, and hence (b) the standard libraries won't help you. Anyway, you'd probably need `delete[]` rather than `delete`. But since strings are not (directly) allocated with `new`, it's not appropriate to think you can take their memory and free it (directly) with `delete[]`.

So, if your real situation is that you need to pass some pre-existing API a buffer that will be freed with `delete[]`, then you'll have to take a copy, just as if you needed to pass some pre-existing API a buffer that will be freed with `free`.

Answer (score 1):

Use `c_str()` to copy the string into C style string. And then use `strcpy()`

Answer (score 0):

There are 2 things you can use, depending on what you need. string::c_str () will copy the characters into a C string you can then use for whatever you need. std::data () will return a pointer to the string, but there are 2 issues: a) it is not NULL terminated like a C string, and b) it will go away when the std::string is deleted. So it doesn't stick around after you delete the original object.

Comment: `c_str` is also gone once you delete the original object. And FWIW in C++11 both `data` and `c_str` return null-terminated strings that point to the internal buffer.

Answer (score 0):

You can copy your string to a new array of char.

```
std::string s = "My string";
char *a = new char[s.size()+1];
a[s.size()]=0;
memcpy(a,s.c_str(),s.size());
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you should always know who owns a particular section of memory the only way to change ownership of a string is to copy it. The simplest way to do this is to just assign the string to another std::string variable. If the ownership changes very often (or you simply cannot clearly determine which specific object is the owner) you'd want to use another implementation of string (or a wrapper for std::string) that supports reference counting, so you don't have to allocate new memory all the time.

Answer (score 0):

U can use it as follows:

```
std::string str = "abcd";
char* cStr = str.c_str();
```

Thanks...:)

Comment: What happens with `cStr` when `str` goes off scope? The answer is - it becomes garbage, because `c_str()` does not detach the `char*` pointer, rather it preserves the respective `std::string` as the owner of the buffer. The essence of detaching is that the string relinquish its ownership on the buffer. I am sorry, but your answer is very very wrong.

Comment: @mark: To do that u can take the ownership of the string, will solve the problem.

Comment: It is not always possible, hence is my question.